# Direct Access to this location is not allowed. Joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.2

I am using Joomla 3.3.3 and I am getting this error "Direct Access to this location is not  allowed."when trying to access the front page. The story about that every thing is working fine .When I create new menu and save it .After saving the new menu I start getting this error .I dont know why this error is coming.
When I do Google about this error I found that remove some unsupported plugins and module.I disabled all plugins and module from Joomla one by one But the error still there. I also remove CB plugins But did not get any  solution.

Is anybody know how to fix this error I will appreciate them .

Please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Is this error appear once you set a specific type of menu item or with all menu types?

Comment: are all your 3rd party extensions up to date? is the menu you're trying to create always of the same type? ensure you update the component the new menu item refers to. Then if you still face the issue, post your server's error log